# Does MPI drop or delay messages?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816658/why-are-some-of-these-mpi-slaves-slow-to-report), but I think it was too long so I'll try again in a shorter way:

I've got a C++ program using the latest OpenMPI on a Rocks cluster under a master/slave setup.  The slaves perform a task and then report data to the master using the blocking MPI_SEND / MPI_RECV calls (through Boost MPI), which writes the data to a database.  The master is currently significantly slower than the slaves.  I'm having trouble with the program because about half of the slaves get stuck on the first task and never report their data;  using strace/ltrace, it seems that they're stuck polling in MPI_SEND and their message never gets received.

I wrote a program to test this theory (again, listed in full [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816658/why-are-some-of-these-mpi-slaves-slow-to-report)) and I can cause a similar problem - slave communications slow down significantly so they do less tasks than they should - by manipulating the speed of the slaves and masters using sleep.  When the speed(master) > speed(slaves), everything works fine.  When speed(master) < speed(slaves), messages get significantly delayed for some slaves every time.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Have a look here for the semantics of MPI_Send/Recv: http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node38.html#SECTION00340000000000000000

Comment: Based on that ... could it be that I'm using MPI_ANY_SOURCE wrong? Are the messages being sent from some slaves (probably in an implementation / setup specific way) getting overtaken because the Recv is matching ... newer messages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are some of these MPI slaves slow to report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816658/why-are-some-of-these-mpi-slaves-slow-to-report)

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah, sorry, that was a deliberate duplicate on my part.  They're both my question;  I just thought that the deluge of detail in the first one might have been scaring away possible answers, so I thought I'd try again.

Comment: @Winawer: I realize that - the "close as duplicate" automatically adds the "possible". :) You should edit your original question to clarify/improve it instead of posting a separate, duplicate question.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you, I'll keep that in mind for the future.  I don't know what to do about it now, though;  the answer to this question could be helpful to others, but it might not make sense without the context of the previous one.  Should I copy the information from the previous question into this one?

Comment: @Winawer: I'm not sure. I'll flag it for a moderator to take a look at, and let them decide how best to handle it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see this results from the recv in the while loop in the master node.

```
 ...
 while (1) {
 // Receive results from slave.
      stat = world.recv(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG);
 ...
```

When there is a message from one slave the master cannot get any messages until the code inside while loop is finished (which take some while as there is a sleep), as the master node is not running parallel. Therefore all other slaves cannot start sending their messages until the first slave has finished sending his message. Then the next slave can start sending the message but then all other slaves are stopped until the code inside the while loop is executed.

This result in the behavior you see, that the slaves communication is very slow. to avoid this problem you need to implement the point to point communication non blocking or use global communications.

**UPDATE 1:**

Lets assume that the master distributed his data. Now he waits until the slaves report back. When the first slave reports back he will first send his REPORTTAG and then his DONETAG. Now the master will send him back a new job if the

```
 currentTask < numtasks
```

Now the slaves start again with his calculation. It might be now the case that until he is finished the master was only able to handle another slave. So the slave of the beginning is now again sending first his REPORTTAG and then his DONETAG and gets an new job. When this continues in the end only 2 slaves have get new jobs and the rest were not able to finish their jobs. So that at some point this is true:

```
 currentTask >= numtasks
```

Now you stop all jobs even not all slaves have reported their data back and have done more than one task.

This problem occurs most when the network connection of the different nodes is highly different. The reason is that the send and receive are not handled after their call, instead the communication takes place if two of these functions are able to make some kind of handshake.

As solutions I would suggest either:

- Make sure that all slaves are finished before killing all jobs
- Use gather and scatter instead of messages, then all slaves synchronized after each task.
- Use buffered or unbuffered send and receive operations, if the messages are not to big. Make sure that you did not get a memory overflow on the Master
- Change from Master/ Slave to a more parallel workmodus, e.g divide all task to two nodes, then divide the tasks further from these nodes to the next two, and so on. In the end send the task this way back. This solution might also have the advantage that the communication cost are only of O(logn) instead of O(n).

Hope this helped.

Comment: But if all of the messages were being received sequentially, just slowly because they're waiting on the master, I would expect the job to take a long time but each slave to perform an equal number of tasks...right?  If so, why aren't they?  If not, what's wrong with my thinking?  It's just *some* of the slaves that slow down, not *all* of them.  And in the full code, some of the slaves get stuck entirely and their messages are never received no matter how long they wait.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the last else { in the while loop. There you try to send new work to the slaves:  
    world.send(stat.source(),TASKTAG);
    world.send(stat.source(),TASKDATATAG,randnum);

Comment: It does actually seem to be a variation on what you're describing here, though it seems that the problem is MPI_ANY_SOURCE.  When I change that ANY_SOURCE to a loop that cycles through the slave sequentially collecting results, the problem disappears and the code works as I expected.  Unless someone has something brilliant to add, though, I'll accept your answer because it got me thinking in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: If you use do not use MPI_ANY_SOURCE you will also synchronize the slaves before sending new tasks to them.